# Share docker-compose volume definition but changing base path

Tags: docker-compose, volume

I need to cite the same volume mount structures among different container.

Use case: two different stage of an app, same dir structure, different code base.

I have a long volumes definition that is shared among the two different containers, but they should differ for the base path of the code. I actually achieved this by copying the volumes configuration (originally stored on `service.yml`) inside a copy named `test.yml` and replacing the variable name (and adding it to `.env` file).

The problem: I would like to delete the file `test.yml` since it is (not always, but 99.999% of time) a copy of the original one, just with the variable replaced.

How can I achieve not repeating all the volumes definition in another file just with different variable name in pure docker-compose syntax?

I tried with the `env_file` variable, but it does only apply to the enviroment of a container and not his mountpoint.

Sharing the 4 files, I hope you could suggest a solution to make them become 3:

```
JOOMLA_SRC_ABS_PATH=/some/abs/path
JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH=/some/abs/test/path
```

Master `docker-compose.yml` (actually they are 2 different file: `docker-compose.yml` and `test-compose.yml` and I run them by `docker-compose -f test-compose.yml up -d` when I need to run the 2 services

```yml
services:
  production:
    image: something
    extends:
      file: ${JOOMLA_SRC_ABS_PATH}/conf/service.yml
      service: joomla

  next:
    image: something
      extends:
        file: ${JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH}/conf/test.yml
        # <---- i want this to become /conf/service.yml since it has ${JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH} in the front
        service: joomla
```

Joomla service `service.yml` (shortned)

```yml
services:
  joomla:
    volumes:
      - ${JOOMLA_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_XXX:/joomla/templates/tpl_XXX
      - ${JOOMLA_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex:/joomla/templates/tpl_ja_gamex
      - ${JOOMLA_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_ja_gamex.ini:/joomla/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_tpl_ja_gamex.ini
      - ${JOOMLA_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex/language/es-ES/es-ES.tpl_ja_gamex.ini:/joomla/language/es-ES/es-ES.tpl_tpl_ja_gamex.ini
      - ${JOOMLA_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex/language/it-IT/it-IT.tpl_ja_gamex.ini:/joomla/language/it-IT/it-IT.tpl_tpl_ja_gamex.ini
      - ${JOOMLA_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_ja_gamex.sys.ini:/joomla/administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_tpl_ja_gamex.sys.ini
```

Joomla `test.yml` (shortned) <----- the file I want to remove

```yml
services:
  joomla:
    volumes:
      - ${JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_XXX:/joomla/templates/tpl_XXX
      - ${JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex:/joomla/templates/tpl_ja_gamex
      - ${JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_ja_gamex.ini:/joomla/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_tpl_ja_gamex.ini
      - ${JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex/language/es-ES/es-ES.tpl_ja_gamex.ini:/joomla/language/es-ES/es-ES.tpl_tpl_ja_gamex.ini
      - ${JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex/language/it-IT/it-IT.tpl_ja_gamex.ini:/joomla/language/it-IT/it-IT.tpl_tpl_ja_gamex.ini
      - ${JOOMLA_TEST_SRC_ABS_PATH}/src/templates/tpl_ja_gamex/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_ja_gamex.sys.ini:/joomla/administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_tpl_ja_gamex.sys.ini
```